# How can I set X-XSS-Protection header in jetty

Tags: eclipse, jetty, xss

I am trying to set X-XSS-Protection header in the server configuration, in Tomcat I dont have problems, but I can not find how to make the same in jetty, I tried to look in the documentation but I did not see a way to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [RewriteHandler](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/rewrite-handler.html) for accomplishing this at the server level. Additionally, you can look into the [HeaderFilter](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/header-filter.html) for implementing this per-webapp.